# Update Grpc.Core Library with zlib 1.3.1

Tags: grpc, zlib

The zlib version is updated in 1.3 in this commit -https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/35147/commits/3bc42c5654bbc9147f9de02df6e76813ed16aeeb . Are there any plans to update the zlib to 1.3.1 version and release a new Grpc.Core Nuget package with it?

I am using Opentelemetry library which uses Grpc.Core, the current scanning of this library is showing zlib vulnerability(CVE-2023-45853) with 1.2.13. Though the API affected by the vulnerability is not used in gRPC.Core. Having zlib 1.3.1 on Grpc.Core would be great.

Answer (score 0):

"Though the API affected by the vulnerability is not used in gRPC.Core." Exactly. So you do not have a problem. That CVE is for minizip, not zlib.

Comment: Thanks Mark Adler for your reply.  Do you have any idea if minizip is used in Grpc.Core library  during compression?

Comment: Minizip is not used by gRPC.